# appendTo function not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to code it such that when you hover and click one word(eg. chocolate, sugar or cocoa", it gives a sentence, click another word, another sentence. and then the rotating words continue rotating.

Any suggestions is deeply appreciated. Thanks, guys:)

checkout my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hE2pk/

HTML:

```
<div id="steps"> 
    <div id="receipe"></div>
   <div id="text"></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var words = [
'<span id="pasta">Penne</span>', 
'<span id="meat">Italian Sausage</span>',
'<span id="oil">Olive Oil</span>', 
'<span id="onion">Onion</span>'

];



var index = 0;


$(document).ready(function rotate() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML =words[(index++)%(words.length)];
  if($("#text").is(":hover")){
    setTimeout(rotate, 500);
  }
  else{
    setTimeout(rotate, 100);
  }
})()


$(function(){
    $('#pasta').on('click', function () {
        $("<p>Cook 8 ounces of pasta, according to its package directions.</p>").appendTo('#receipe');

        $("#steps").html('<div id="text"></div>'); 
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

1. Appends `<span id="pasta">…</span>` to the DOM
2. Attaches a click handler to it
3. Replaces `<span id="pasta">…</span>` with `<span id="meat">…</span>` 100ms later

As soon as step #3 finishes, the `#pasta` span gets obliterated, along with the click handler!

The correct approach is to use **event delegation**. This is a technique where you attach an event handler higher up in the DOM (on something that you can reasonably expect not to be destroyed, like `document`), then listen for events that bubble up toward it. If the event originated from an element of interest, you fire your handler!

```
$(document).on('click', '#pasta', function() { ... });
```

Here's your example, fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/steveluscher/hE2pk/1/

Comment: thank you so much. quick qn: i realise that you removed this"$(document).ready", why is that? the moment I removed this, my onClick worked

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { … })` and `$(function() { … })` are equivalent in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/ready/